# Можете подробно раскомментировать код начиная строки array_map?

Tags: php, условия, замыкания

```
 $arr = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple", "MongoDB", "Zoomer-19"]; 

    $result = [];
    $length = 0;
    array_map(function($v) use (&$length) {
        if ($length < mb_strlen($v)) {
            $length = mb_strlen($v);
        }
    }, $arr);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($length == mb_strlen($value)) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
  echo join(" ",$result);
```

Код для меня в принципе понятен, но это часть кода не совсем

```
array_map(function($v) use (&$length) {
            if ($length < mb_strlen($v)) {
                $length = mb_strlen($v);
            }
        }, $arr);
```

Если не сложно можете объяснить для чего эта часть кода `use (&$length)` и это и почему она за скобками ?

```
}, $arr);
```

Comment: это типа поиск элементов минимально длины? саму минимальную длину проще найти через `min(array_map('mb_strlen', $arr))`

Comment: я то могу, но тут всего 3 функции, уж попробуйте почитать на них документацию.

Comment: $arr = ["Ceylon", "Fish", "Apple",  "Zoomer-19","soonminz"]; 
 $result = [];
$length = 0;
 min(array_map('mb_strlen', $arr));
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($length == mb_strlen($value)) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($result);  выводит array(0) {
}

Comment: `$length = min(...)`

Comment: Спасибо помогло, но вывод только 1 минимально/максимальное значения, я хочу чтоб выводило, все минимальные или максимальные значения массива вот пример : arr=["12", "1", "123"]  или arr=["1234", "1234567", "1234567899"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *для чего эта часть кода use (&$length)?*

Оператор `use()` выполняет импорт переменных из глобальной области видимости в локальную. Амперсанд `&`, стоящий перед переменной `$length`, указывает на то, что значение в локальную область передаётся по ссылке. Иначе говоря, если в теле функции будет изменено значение переменной `$length`, то эти изменения будут отражены и в глобальной области видимости.

> *почему она за скобками ?*

Потому, что `use()` не является аргументом callback-функции.